# When should I use inheritance over utility classes?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am working on a project that uses `Canvas` objects. I would like to add a few functionalities to manipulate them.

Until now, I was adding them in a `CanvasUtils` class but now I realize that I could actually create a `CustomCanvas` class that would inherit from `Canvas` and implement the new functionalities.

I can feel the second way is more intuitive but I am not sure whether it is the best option or not.
For example, if I keep adding new methods to a `CustomCanvas` class it is going to become huge at some point whereas I can easily break a utils class into several ones.

Also a `Utils` class sounds more independent and extendable to me. For example, if I wanted to extend some of the functionalities to `Panel` objects (`Canvas` inherits from `Panel`), I think it would be easier to do it with a `Utils` class as you just have to change the `Canvas` references to `Panel`.

My questions are:

1. **what** are the advantages and flaws of each method and
2. **when** should I use one over another?

Comment: It's always hard to talk about design in general. One learns this - in many cases - by *trail-and-error*...

Comment: I am aware of that. But if you can take advantage of others people's experience, it is better than constantly reinventing the wheel on your own. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are adding new functionality, then you should extend the class.  You'll be able to add your own state, as well as methods to interact with them.  However, you won't be able to add this functionality to existing objects.

If you are simply writing shortcuts that use existing functionality, then you can use [Extension Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb383977.aspx) to add functions without needing to extend the class.  For example...

```
public static class PanelExtensions    
{
    public static void DoSomething(this Panel panel) 
    {
        panel.SomePanelMethod();
        panel.SomeOtherPanelMethod();
    }
}
```

And then to use this...

```
Panel myPanel = new Panel();
myPanel.DoSomething();
```

The advantage of this approach is that the methods are available to existing panels, and they will be inherited too (so your Canvas objects will receive these methods too).

Note than in order to use extension methods, you need to have a `using` statement at the top of your file referencing the namespace in which they are defined.

Comment: This example does not really makes sense. Why would it be better to use `myPanel.DoSomething()` instead of `myPanel.SomePanelMethod()`? Extension methods are actually ment for circumvent the lack of multiple implementation inheritance in C#.

Comment: @GáborAngyal *Extension methods are actually ment for circumvent the lack of multiple implementation inheritance in C#* Not true; extension methods are added to support `Linq`; that has nothing to do with multiple inheritance. What you're talking about is the job of an interface.

Comment: In this example where I'm doing one thing, yes it's pointless.  But consider when you might regularly do 10 things to a panel, then it makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel _"extension methods are added to support `Linq`"_ True. But the reason why LINQ could not be implemented without extension method is that C# does not support multiple implementation inheritance. Otherwise there would be an Enumerable abstract class implementing all LINQ functionality.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve and what do you need to implement new functionality:

1. If you have stateless methods that do not need any additional information associated with object, then you can either continue to use Util methods or turn them into [Extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) that will give you both the inheritance-like feel of use and loose coupling of the Util class:

   ```
   public static class CanvasExtensions
   {
       public static void TransformElements(this Canvas canvas,
           Action<CanvasElement> transform)
       {
           ...
           foreach(var elem in canvas.Children)
           {
               transform(elem);
           }
           ...
       }
   }
   ```
2. If you need to associate some piece of info with the object you operate on, then:

   - you can either inherit the class if the object's behaviour shall be deeply affected by additional functionality (like when other standard methods can negate new functionality) to allow base function overriding:

     ```
     public class DeeplyAffectedCanvas : Canvas
     {
         private IDictionary<CanvasElement, Action> m_dictionary;

         public void SpecialTransform(CanvasElement elem, Action transform) { }

         public override void Resize() 
         { 
             // Resize, for example, have to take into account
             // the special operation
         }
     }
     ```
   - or create a wrapper, that exposes the original object (Panel) when the additional behaviour doesn't affect the wrapped object much:

     ```
     public class Wrapper<T>
     {
        public Wrapper(T wrapped)
        {
            this.Wrapped = wrapped;
        }

        public T Wrapped { get; private set; }

        public implicit operator T (Wrapper<T> wrapper)
        {
            return wrapper.Wrapped;
        }
     }

     public class WrappedCanvas : Wrapper<Canvas>
     {
         private Object data;
         public void SafeTransform(...);
     }
     ```